# How do you split a String into a [String] and not [Substring]?

Tags: swift, split, swift4

Consider the following extension:

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    func foo(){
    }
}
```

And consider the following string that I want to split so I can use the extension...

```
let string = "This|is|a|test"
let words = string.split(separator: "|")
```

The problem is `words` is a `[Substring]` and not `[String]` so I can't call `foo()` on it.

So in Swift 4, how do I split a string to return a `[String]` and not a `[Substring]`?

Comment: `string.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)` will return an array of strings

Comment: If you really need to use split method you can map them into strings `.map(String.init)`

Comment: `string.components(separatedBy: ."|")`

Comment: Ideally you'd modify the extension to work with substrings, I presume

Comment: @JohnDvorak, I had just posted a second question specifically asking how to write an extension that works with both.  Can you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: @MarqueIV I can't, sorry, but I'd be willing to read an answer to that :-D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Leo said above, you can use `components(separatedBy:)`

```
let string = "This|is|a|test"
let words = string.components(separatedBy: "|")
words.foo()
```

instead, that returns a `[String]`.

If you want to stick with
`split()` (e.g. because it has more options, such as to omit
empty subsequences), then you'll have to create a new array by converting each `Substring`
to a `String`:

```
let string = "This|is|a|test"
let words = string.split(separator: "|").map(String.init)
words.foo()
```

Alternatively – if possible – make the array extension method more
general to take arguments conforming to the `StringProtocol` protocol,
that covers both `String` and `Substring`:

```
extension Array where Element: StringProtocol {
    func foo(){
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. And your `StringProtocol` solution actually answers my other question that I just posted.  Feel free to copy it there and I'll accept that there as well.