# What's the difference between Element == StringProtocol and Element: StringProtocol?

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-extensions

I keep seeing different syntax for how to extend an array. Here are the two that I'm seeing.  Can someone explain what the difference is?

```
extension Array where Element == StringProtocol {
    func foo(){}
}

extension Array where Element:StringProtocol {
    func foo(){}
}
```

So what's the difference?

Bonus:

I'm trying to write an extension that works with `[String]` and `[Substring]` and it was suggested that I base it on `StringProtocol`, hence the above. However, if I try doing something like the following...

```
func foo(separator:Character)

    for line in self{

        let components = line.split(separator: separator, maxSplits: 1, omittingEmptySubsequences: false)

        let prefix = components[0].replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+$", with: "", options: .regularExpression) // Only trim the end of the prefix
        let suffix = components.count > 1
            ? components[1].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) // Perform full trim on the suffix
            : nil
        ...
    }

}
```

I get this...

> Member 'split' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'StringProtocol'; use a generic constraint instead

So how do you say `Element` is a `T` where `T` conforms to `StringProtocol`?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what you want to achieve? An example of a `foo()` method that fails to compile as an extension method?

Comment: Done. See my edit.

Comment: And also, can you clarify the difference in the first part of the question?

Comment: It should be  `where Element: StringProtocol` , and then your code compiles in my Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Then I get a different error.  Added more code to show that one.  Starting to think the solution is just to convert it to a `[String]` as the first part of the code.  That way it doesn't matter how I enter, but I'll always be working with an array of Strings internally.

Comment: `components` is an array of  `Substring` and that has no `replacingOccurrences` method. So you have to convert it to a `String` array : `let components = line.split(...).map(String.init)` as in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49206208/1187415

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** In this particular use-case,

```
extension Array where Element: StringProtocol {}
```

is what you want. It defines an extension for arrays of `T` where `T` conforms to `StringProtocol`. On the other hand,

```
extension Array where Element == StringProtocol {}
```

defines an extension for arrays of type `[StringProtocol]` which are
– as far as I can tell – impossible to create because that protocol
has associated type requirements.

---

**Long answer:** Let's do this for a simple protocol which has
no associated types:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var id: Int { get }
}

extension Array where Element: MyProtocol {
    func foo() {
        for elem in self { print(elem.id) }
    }
}

extension Array where Element == MyProtocol {
    func bar() {
        for elem in self { print(elem.id) }
    }
}
```

and two types conforming to the protocol

```
struct A: MyProtocol {
    let id: Int
}
struct B: MyProtocol {
    let id: Int
}
```

Then I can call `foo()` on arrays of type `[A]` and of type `[B]`
because both  `A` and `B` conform to `MyProtocol`:

```
let aArray = [A(id: 1), A(id: 2), A(id: 3)]
let bArray = [B(id: 4), B(id: 5), B(id: 6)]

aArray.foo()
bArray.foo()
```

On the other hand, `bar()` can be called on an array of type
`[MyProtocol]`, which is an array of “boxes” where each box can
hold any value of a type conforming to that protocol:

```
let pArray: [MyProtocol] = [A(id: 10), B(id: 11)]
pArray.bar()
```

(See [Type conversion when using protocol in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387256/type-conversion-when-using-protocol-in-swift/38387367#38387367) for more information
about that.) But this does not compile

```
aArray.bar() // '[A]' is not convertible to 'Array<MyProtocol>'
```

unless the array is converted explicitly to an array of type `[MyProtocol]`:

```
(aArray as [MyProtocol]).bar()
```

which creates a new array and is a `O(N)` operation, as explained in
above-mentioned answer. And vice versa,

```
pArray.foo() // Using 'MyProtocol' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'MyProtocol' is not supported
```

does not compile because [a protocol does not conform to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/1187415).